# How to wake up sleeping process?

Tags: linux, bash

Shell script runs two functions as child processes (via &).
Both of them went to sleep (via sleep command).

Is it possible to wake them?

I have their pids.

P.s.

I don't want to run sleep with & and wait

Comment: Running `sleep` doesn't mean they are suspended forever. [What are you actually trying to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: to wakeup from sleeping knowing that it's not needed anymore.

Comment: A code snippet might help.

Answer (score 1):

A rather barbaric way to do this would be to kill the `sleep` process (not the whole subshell in which your script/function runs). Consider the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 20
echo "Done!"
```

or, with a function:

```
#!/bin/bash

function gotosleep()
{
    sleep 20
    echo "Done!"
}

gotosleep &
sleep 60 # Not really necessary, keeps the script in foreground.
```

Then, find the `sleep` process:

```
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
you    PID    PGID  ... sleep 20
```

And kill it:

```
$ kill PID
```

You script will then output (at least in `bash`):

```
./script.sh: line 2: PID Terminated    sleep 20
Done!
```

Since you don't want to `wait` properly, you'll have to do with Bash's little message. If you change your mind, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719030/bash-silently-kill-background-function-process):

```
sleep 20 &
if wait $! 2>/dev/null; then
    # Keep working
    continue
else
    echo "Done!"
    return # from function
fi
```

Comment: I don't like the idead of sleeping in a new subprocees ( at least not explicitly)

Comment: @yuris That's not what I'm doing here. I believe my `sleep` process runs in the same "shell" the function does (if you use a function). The only time I used `&` was to send the function to background, which is exactly what you did.

Comment: I see, the issue will be greping the correct pid...